# Updating Jersey 1.16 to Jersey 2.11

Tags: java, jersey, updates, web.xml

I'm currently updating a project from 1.16 to 2.11 and I'm facing this problem with the web.xml:

```
<init-param> 
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name> 
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilter</param-value> 
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilterConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>HEADER</param-value>
</init-param>
```

jersey hasn't any `com.sun.x` packages left so these two can't work like that and I can't figure out how I can do the same thing as in the `web.xml` with the new jersey.

Any help is appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.HttpMethodOverrideFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.3.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/HttpMethodOverrideFilter.html) instead of com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilterConfig.